# Django-CMS node tags in breadcrumbs template

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I want to create custom breadcrumbs template for my site developed with django-cms.

It should display levels (number) of items in addition to item title. I've read this [article](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/basic_reference/navigation.html) and it seems that I should use {{ node.level }} like this, for example:

```
{% for ance in ancestors %}
<li>
    {% if not forloop.last %}
    <a href="{{ ance.get_absolute_url }}">**{{ ance.level }}** - {{ ance.get_menu_title }}</a> <span class="separator">&raquo;</span>
    {% else %}
    <span class="active">**{{ ance.level }}** -{{ ance.get_menu_title }}</span>
    {% endif %}
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

But this is didn't working. I exepected to see "0 - Main ..." but see only " - Main ..."

And I am also curious about **get_menu_title** because I didn't find that in documentation, but I am find **{{ node.title }}** and it seems working same as **get_menu_title**